# VS2008: Breakpoints window gone while debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, breakpoints

This is probably silly but very frustrating.
Using VS2008 with a C++ project, when I'm working normally, the breakpoints window is visible and active but when I'm debugging it disappears and can't be shown. This is a problem if I want to edit the condition of a breakpoint while running.
Pressing the breakpoints window button doesn't do anything and neither does pressing Ctrl+Alt+B

Does this happen to anybody else? It's a brand new install with Visual Assist and QT integration as extensions. same configuration with VS2005 doesn't have any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to export the settings using `"Tools->Import and Export Settings"` Then, using the same wizard, to reset the settings to the default and then when re-importing the saved settings file uncheck the "Windows Layout" item in the import list.
This allowed me to save all the my previous settings and reset only the windows layout and not the breakpoints window is finally visible.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to reset Visual Studio Layouts by launching Visual Studio with the following command line:

```
devenv.exe /resetuserdata
```

More info [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb245788(vs.80).aspx#vs05idetips_topic6)

Answer (score 1):

[Debug] -> [Windows] -> [Breakpoints]

Comment: Maybe not exactly relevant to the question, but it did answer my question via google...

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools->Customize.
Select Commands tab
Click on the 'Rearrange Commands' button towards the bottom.
Select 'Menu Bar' on the radio button at the top.
In the drop down in front of it, select 'Debug | Windows'.
Click the 'Add' button on the right, 'Add Command' prompt opens.
select 'Debug' on the left, Breakpoints on the right and click 'OK' button.
Now you should be able to see 'Breakpoints' in 'Debug->Windows' menu.
Select it to pop the window up.

Answer (score 0):

There is a menu item Window->Reset Window Layout.

Comment: Did you try it in debug mode, when you miss the window? There are different window settings for debugging and "normal" mode.