# Reset VS 2008 toolbars

Tags: visual-studio-2008, toolbar

How do I completely reset my Visual Studio 2008 toolbar? Right now I have toolbars randomly appearing/disappering when I write code vs. debug. Is this expected behavior?

I'd like to get it to a point where the same set of toolbars appears and sticks to their same position in the toolbar area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also run one of the following commands (if you can't get it to work in the command line in VS, run the regular command prompt in Windows. As Admin, if you're running Vista...):

"Mild" versions

```
devenv /resetskippkgs
devenv /resetsettings
```

"Hardcore" version

```
devenv /setup
```

This one takes some time to complete, so be patient... Also, note that it will reset **all** of the settings, not just the menus. But if you look in the documentation for the `devenv` command you'll probably find a flag that resets just the menu options.

Comment: I just did a 'devenv /resetsettings". Its the closest thing I could find.

Comment: I got that in there, for future reference. =)

Answer (score 3):

On the Tools menu, choose Export and Import settings.  That provides you with many options, including the option to reset settings.

Having said that, VS does keep a different toolbar set for debugging. So any changes you make, you have to make to both the debugging and the normal set.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is normal.

Each toolbar has a view setting for each mode, you should change them manually to make them the same.

Answer (score 1):

1. To to *Tools -> Import Export Settings*
2. Select "Import selected environment settings" and click next
3. Select "Yes, save my current settings" and click next
4. Choose a default and click next
5. Unselect all settings. Select *All Settings -> General Settings -> Menu and Command Bar Customization* and click finish

Answer (score 0):

using

> devenv /resetsettings

or something of this sort will also reset may other options you've every configured. This is too drastic for something as trivial as arranging the GUI. I found a better solution a while ago.

See my eventual answer to this question:

[VS2008: Breakpoints window gone while debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632761/vs2008-breakpoints-window-gone-while-debugging)